# How do I copy photos from my iPhone on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, iphone

I  plugged in my iPhone 5 with iOS 10 and saw iPhone in the file explorer. I clicked on the iPhone 'drive' but it was blank. There was  a button for ShotWell and I clicked on that. Another 'folder' for iPhone was there too, but when I clicked on it, it said 'Importing, please wait...' and didn't do anything.

[image: iphone drive in ubuntu file manager]

Ubuntu 16.04, iPhone 5, iOS 10.1.1

Comment: Use the steps described [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html) under The proper solution , before installing the required package check for the newest package version One by one

Comment: @GAD3R This part didn't work: `$ sudo ifuse /media/chloe/iPhone --root
GnuTLS error: Error in the pull function.
Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.` It didn't work after I rebooted the phone either.

Comment: follow this answer on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/812379/498780)

Comment: OK I didn't install or build anything because I  already had the latest version from `apt`, but after I edited `fuse.conf` according to that answer, and used the file explorer, then it worked. It still doesn't work in the command line though.

Comment: Maybe the problem come from the `libimobiledevice` try to compile it from git repo , see [here](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/commit/23069d10341ce637fdad7321d447c53752dba48c)

Comment: I tried and tried and tried. Not worth it. Also, each solution can break in the next iOS update. Now I just set Dropbox to upload all my photos and it works beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to download the files from my iPhone.  I was able to get the pictures from my Free Google Drive account.  Drive is one of the options one can download iPhone pictures into.  Go to your Google account on the Lubuntu computer, and download them from there.

Comment: Fooled around and got it to work, after iPhone asked to Trust the computer.